# Concatenation of the result of a function with a mutable default argument

Tags: python, language-lawyer

Suppose a function with a mutable default argument:

```
def f(l=[]):
    l.append(len(l))
    return l
```

If I run this:

```
def f(l=[]):
    l.append(len(l))
    return l
print(f()+["-"]+f()+["-"]+f()) # -> [0, '-', 0, 1, '-', 0, 1, 2]
```

Or this:

```
def f(l=[]):
    l.append(len(l))
    return l
print(f()+f()+f()) # -> [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2]
```

Instead of the following one, which would be more logical:

```
print(f()+f()+f()) # -> [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2]
```

**Why?**

Comment: if you want to see the result of individual functional call then use `return [l.copy()]`

Comment: Well the last funciont returns me this: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: @CeliusStingher You have to redefine the function between uses.

Comment: with `-` you will be able to distinguish between your data from each functional call , in second one you need to write a code to get the pattern

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: Definitely not a dupe of that one

Answer (score 53, accepted):

That's actually pretty interesting!

As we know, the list `l` in the function definition is initialized only once at the definition of this function, and for all invocations of this function, there will be *exactly one* copy of this list. Now, the function modifies this list, which means that multiple calls to this function will modify the exact same object multiple times. This is the first important part.

Now, consider the expression that adds these lists:

```
f()+f()+f()
```

According to the laws of operator precedence, this is equivalent to the following:

```
(f() + f()) + f()
```

...which is exactly the same as this:

```
temp1 = f() + f() # (1)
temp2 = temp1 + f() # (2)
```

This is the second important part.

Addition of lists produces a *new* object, without modifying any of its arguments. This is the third important part.

Now let's combine what we know together.

In line 1 above, the first call returns `[0]`, as you'd expect. The second call returns `[0, 1]`, as you'd expect. Oh, wait! The function will return the *exact same object* (not its copy!) over and over again, after modifying it! This means that the object that the first call returned has now *changed* to become `[0, 1]` as well! And that's why `temp1 == [0, 1] + [0, 1]`.

The result of addition, however, is a *completely new object*, so `[0, 1, 0, 1] + f()` is the same as `[0, 1, 0, 1] + [0, 1, 2]`. Note that the second list is, again, exactly what you'd expect your function to return. The same thing happens when you add `f() + ["-"]`: this creates a *new* `list` object, so that any other calls to `f` won't interfere with it.

You can reproduce this by concatenating the results of *two* function calls:

```
>>> f() + f()
[0, 1, 0, 1]
>>> f() + f()
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> f() + f()
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Again, you can do all that because you're concatenating references to *the same object*.

Comment: Wow, . The best thing about this answer is that it is right. `[]+f()+f()` gives `[0, 0, 1]` and `f()+f()+[]` gives `[0, 1, 0, 1]` !!!

Comment: it's just how the python print  process the functional call, either preprocess or post processs

Comment: The new object returned by `+` is definitely the key here, it's so subtle

Comment: A good reminder for why a mutable default argument is a big no-no.

Comment: @BenoîtPilatte, yep! I've also edited my answer to clarify the part about the result of addition being a new object.

Comment: Looked into `dis(lambda: f()+f()+f())` and the function `f` did get called twice before `add` is performed. Great answer btw.

Comment: @HenryYik it's because of how `list.__add__` is implemented. The first `f()` instantiates the list object, let's call it `l1`. Then `l1.__add__(f())` is called, so, `f()` needs to be evaluated *first*, which changes the reference that is shared with `l1`. Then `l1.__add__(l2)` finishes, returning the new object.

Comment: @C.Nivs that was actually much easier to understand than operator precedence!

Comment: @EliadL You could conceivably use a mutable default as some sort of cache on a function to keep track of calls. Now, this would probably be better suited for a `class` or `lru` cache, but as a naive or small example, I wouldn't say it's a *horrible* idea

Comment: Thank you for describing this by breaking down the expression into separate statements. That's generally my preferred way of explaining complex expressions like this, and I find that it really aids understanding.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way to think about it that might help it make sense:

A function *is a data structure*.  You create one with a `def` block, much the same way as you create a type with a `class` block or you create a list with square brackets.

The most interesting part of that data structure is the *code* that gets run when the function is called, but the default arguments are also part of it!  In fact, you can inspect *both* the code and the default arguments from Python, via attributes on the function:

```
>>> def foo(a=1): pass
... 
>>> dir(foo)
['__annotations__', '__call__', '__class__', '__closure__', '__code__', '__defaults__', ...]
>>> foo.__code__
<code object foo at 0x7f114752a660, file "<stdin>", line 1>
>>> foo.__defaults__
(1,)
```

(A much nicer interface for this is [`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#introspecting-callables-with-the-signature-object), but all it does is [examine those attributes](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/inspect.py#L2117).)

So the reason that this modifies the list:

```py
def f(l=[]):
    l.append(len(l))
    return l
```

is exactly the same reason that this also modifies the list:

```py
f = dict(l=[])
f['l'].append(len(f['l']))
```

In both cases, you're mutating a list that belongs to some parent structure, so the change will naturally be visible in the parent as well.

---

Note that this is a design decision that Python specifically made, and it's not inherently necessary in a language.  JavaScript recently learned about default arguments, but it treats them as expressions to be re-evaluated anew on each call —  essentially, each default argument is its own tiny function.  The advantage is that JS doesn't have this gotcha, but the drawback is that you can't meaningfully inspect the defaults the way you can in Python.

Comment: I think the OP is generally aware of the "mutable default argument" issue and why it happens. This question is more complicated.

Comment: The general problem of mutable default arguments is explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: I think this answer should stay there or be fused to the accepted answer as it contains some complementary information that can be useful to understand the accepted answer and the question in the first place. (or at least include @Barmar's link, but I prefer self-contained answers)